# CakePHP Check referer

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code in my CakePHP app home controller:

```
public function index ()
{
    if($this->referer(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')))
    {
        $this->layout = 'splash';

        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Goodbye');

        $this->render('loggedout');
    }
    else
    {
        if (!$this->Auth->user())
        {
            $this->layout = 'splash';

            $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Welcome to CreatHive');

            $this->render('splash'); 

        }
        else
        {

            $this->layout = 'home';

            $this->set('title_for_layout', 'CreatHive');

            $this->render('index');

        }
    }
}
```

Basically it says if the user came from the logout action show the loggedout view but if not then check if they are logged in and either show the splash page or home page.

However it ALWAYS shows the logged out view regardless of being logged in or not or even coming from the logout action (even flushing sessions/cookies etc doesn't work)

Any ideas what the problem is as the code looks fine to me :/

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `debug( $this->referer() );` ?

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
if($this->referer(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')))
```

To:

```
if($this->referer() == Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')))
```

Comment: Causes this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method HomeController::url() in /Users/cameron/Sites/thehive/app/controllers/home_controller.php on line 18`

Comment: Sorry, that should have been Router::url(), not $this->url().  Answer has been updated.

Comment: I echo'd the code you have provided and it is the correct url but for some reason Cake isn't showing the different view when coming from it... any ideas why?

Comment: Did you echo both sides? Maybe there's a slight difference between `$this->referer()` and `Router::url(...)`.

Comment: It helped me in some other context, +1

Comment: $this->referer() gives the full url (with domain name).
Setting the second parameter of Router::url to true will get the full url of the action as well.

Comment: good solution, but won't work if the $this->referer got parameters.